# Error while parsing the json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have an node js code like this:

```
app.post('/', function(request, response){
    var data = JSON.parse(request.body)  
});
```

the line :

```
var data = JSON.parse(request.body)
```

does parse the request.

Using curl I do this:

```
curl -d '{"operation":"test"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

It always return this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
    at /Users/admin/programs/node/test.js:28:18
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request]
```

whats wrong here?

Comment: May be your `request.body` is already parsed. Check by `console.log` >> it's value. `JSON.parse` takes a `String`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.body` is already parsed. You don't need to parse it. you are applying `JSON.parse` on a object rather than a string. Thats the reason for the error you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

This is enough

```
var data = request.body;
```